# Is Uno Platform supported in Visual Studio for Mac Community Edition?

Tags: uno-platform

What I understood from UNO-Platform is that the UWP is the main platform that the UNO is fed its translation of XAML code.

I am a Mac user and I have Visual Studio for mac The Community edition. This version is not supported by UWP thats why the UNO UWP folder is giving a warning. Therefore, it seems that it is quite impossible to built on from VS for mac community

I also tried with VS Code to run the UNO platform, as I only need the WebAssembly version.

I developed a cross-platform app from Xamarin that is not a problem but VS Code is giving an error in the InitializeComponent() method and also it doesn't recognize the names in C# where I mentioned them in xaml.

Could you help me out with that?

Comment: 1) Uno is not UWP. You need to create Uno projects using their own templates in Visual Studio. 2) Uno apps can be developed on macOS in VS for Mac, but there is no visual designer. So, you really should develop it on Windows and then port to macOS. VS Code is completely a different thing, so hope you can edit your question to remove any ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

As this time, Uno Platform in Visual Studio for mac only supports iOS, Android, and macOS heads.

If you want to build your application for WebAssembly, you'll indeed need to use VS Code. To build for VS Code, you'll need to do the following:

- Install the Uno Platform templates:

```
dotnet new -i Uno.ProjectTemplates.Dotnet::2.4
```

- Create a solution with WebAssembly support only:

```
dotnet new unoapp -o MyApp -ios=false -android=false -macos=false -uwp=false --vscodeWasm
```

- Open VS Code:

```
code ./MyApp
```

- Open the Debug tab in code
- In the Run combo box, start the “.NET Core Launch (Uno Platform App)”
- Once the build has finished you can Ctrl+Click on the http://localhost:5000 url in the build output

You can find more details in [this blog post](https://platform.uno/blog/announcing-uno-platform-support-for-visual-studio-code/).

Comment: Mr Laban, I was aware of that. But unfortunately still both app.xaml.cs and mainpage.xaml.cs gives the same initializecomponent() method error.

Comment: Mr Laban, also as I've mentioned XAML defined names can not be recognized by C#. It also still gives error

Comment: What does it mean "cannot be recogized by C#" ? Is it inside the VS code designer ? Or is it when you're Running the app ?